# Show your chosen tags first under the initial/default list of questions

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

The initial questions page after login should be the ones showing those questions on your added/favorite tags. Since they are your favorites, it sort of works as *the tags you follow*.

Every time I go to any Stack Exchange site, I would always need to go to tags again and again.

This feature would sort of work like Facebook's news feed/timeline, but instead you get the latest questions from the tags you are following. I know the questions tab needs to be retained as is but couldn't we have another tab that would display the ones I mentioned above as the default?

Anyway, in my own experience, since I don't know much about other languages like Ruby or Python (I'm more of a PHP guy), then seeing Ruby or Python questions doesn't seem useful in the default page. Instead having a default page of PHP and all other tags I added would seem more helpful. If users insist to look for other questions, there is the old *question* tab or the old *tags* tab which users can navigate to.

Comment: See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/ and also: http://kevinmontrose.com/2013/05/22/your-future-on-stack-overflow/

Comment: @Shog9 didn't know about this till now. thanks!

Comment: You can work around this by creating a custom search page and bookmark it (I have it start up when Chrome starts). It will automatically refresh itself and notify you when new questions are posted. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+c%23+or+asp.net+or+asp.net-mvc-4+or+asp.net-mvc+or+monodroid+or+xamarin+or+android?sort=newest&pageSize=15

Answer (score 1):

this is why you have in your personal page the `prefs` option. Add tags that you want to see question of (under Favorite Tags), and this will highlight them in the main page.

Alternatively,  use a link to get into SO that reflects your preference, for example:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php
```

Comment: yes it highlights it, but it still is a clutter. You would tend to scroll a lot just because there are more non-highlighted questions than the highlighted ones.. which usually, you overlook/or are not interested with anyway. *(not sure if it's only me that thinks this way though)*

Comment: Also noting that questions with awesome-but-not-popular tags like [google-visualization] will never ever pop up on the front page unless you just answered one. So highlighting them doesn't do much.